# Timed sales in different timezones

Tags: php, timeout, timezone, timed

working on a website that will sell one item each day that will run for a period of hours specified by me. The site is much like groupon where when the timelimit is up, it will end the deal. My problem is how do i go about implementing this worldwide where different countries have different timezones? Im trying to refrain from using javascript because people sometimes have it disabled.

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I dont understand is that if it will "run for a period of hours specified by you" then it doesn´t matter in which timezone they are in.

You should just make a Timer (Countdown) that starts counting backwards since the item is created.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a deal to be on sale for the same hours throughout all timezones (e.g. 10am-6pm locally in all timezones) it probably won't happen. There is no reliable way to get the visitor's timezone. You can try javascript, however it can be off or easily spoofed. Your best bet is to just do a countdown time and just say "There are 6 hours and 35 minutes left...buy it while they last!".